# How to conditionally dissolve a vectorized layer?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, dissolve, conditional

I have a raster layer with the day of the year on which we observe temperature above 15 degrees. There are large differences (image below):

[image: first]

I have vectorized this layer based on the Band including the information on day of the year, and now I would like to dissolve these into two different polygons.

[image: second]

The two different areas, seen in the raster image, are adjacent to each other so they will never become two different polygons with the simple `dissolve` tool. However, the neighbouring pixels differ by more than 5 days, so I would like to dissolve these conditionally. More specifically, I would like to dissolve the individual vectorized pixel into one polygon if the neighbouring pixel does not differ with more than 5 days.

Is this possible in QGIS or eventually Python? If so, how?

EDIT:

According to Babel's comment, I potentially have to use `aggregate`. My data is relatively large - with lots of these "heat islands" ranging from day of the year 65 to 345.

1. I want to aggregate/merge/join adjacent polygons if their values of the field `doy` are `< 5`.
2. So I cannot use specific values like `"doy" > 130 AND "doy" < 136`, as it would leave out the other pixels.

How can I use an expression that allows me to aggregate neighbour pixels if their (`"doy" < 5`)?

[image: third]

Comment: Have a look at `Aggregate`: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#aggregate - for further help: can you share the raster and/or polygon layer?

Comment: @Babel, seems correct. Do you have an idea with the expression to use?
The field is called `doy`. So something like `"doy" <6`. Would that work?

Comment: I don't exactly know how your data structure looks like (what kind/how many values you have), but I would try something like `doy >130 and doy<=135?`. You could also use select by expression and than merge the selected polygons: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?#merge-selected-features

Comment: Does my edition help @Babel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#aggregate), based on an expression that categorizes your values. See my example of a grid with random values (field `doy`) for each cell from 1 to 20. I created four groups: 1 to 5, 6 to 10, 11 to 15, 16 to 20 with this expression - you can use it in the aggregate dialog:

```
floor ((doy-1)/5)
```

Explanation: `floor` rounds a number downwards, thus you get integer numbers - the same for each value from 0 to 4 (as we want 1 to 5: `doy-1`:

- 0/5=0
- 1/5=0.2 - rounded downwards: 0
- 2/5=0.4 - rounded downwards: 0

etc.

- 5/5=1
- 6/5=1.2 -rounded downwards:1
- 7/5=1.4 -rounded downwards:1

etc.

*Screenshot: cells grouped together/aggregated with the above expression:*
[image]

Comment: It sort of works. However, some pixels will be split irrationally because of the groups being created. E.g. pixel value 194 is in a different group than pixel value 195. That is not entirely what I wanted. I would like to aggregate adjacent pixels if their values are within a range of 5 days. How can I do that?

Comment: Of course, you have to adapt the expression to the values you have. That's what I did with `doy-1` to get "neat" categories. You first have to define your categories (like: from 151 to 195, from 196 to 200 etc.) and than adapt your expression to that.

Comment: I understand that. I have tried the following `floor((doy - 65) / 26)`. I have done this as, the minimum value is `65`, and the range from min to max is 260 days. So I create 10 groups via `/26`. But if I change the latter to `floor((doy-65 / 52)` to create 5 groups, it still splits at doy 194 and 195. How come it always splits there?

Comment: Dividing by 26 returns you the first 26 values assigned to the first category: 65-90. The next 26 go to category 2: 91 to 116 and so on: category 7 from 247 to 272 (thus the last category will contain only values up to 260, as this is your maximum). You have totally 196 (possible) values: from 65 to 260.
So now you have to divide up these values in a way that 194 (at position 130) and 195 (at position 131) go to the same category.

Comment: You want to get a pattern with a difference of 5: 1 to 5, 6 to 10, 11 to 15 etc. Thus your first value (65) belongs to another category than the second one (166). That's why you have to use this expression: `floor((doy- 66) / 5)`. First category (for 65) will be -1, second category for 66 to 70 will be 0 etc. You can add 1 to the result to get positive values: `1+floor((doy- 66) / 5)`.

Comment: I understand that and thanks for all your help - but no matter what I divide with, I can get a situation in which other adjacent pixels eventually get split into a different group even though they differ with one day. If I divide with `100` that means `doy 164` and `doy 165` are split into different groups. That is simply the nature of the expression. I am searching for an expression where pixels are merged if their values do not differ more than 5 days  - sort of a "running" merge - without setting up groups that are limited by a minimum and maximum value. You get it? Thanks.

Comment: OK - but did you think what consequences that would have conceptually? It will lead to many inconsistencies and even theoretically, depending on which pixel you start with, you will get many differing results. So the very principle you want to base your groups on will lead to an arbitrary result. Let's say you will get a group that consists of values ranging from 65 to 100, whereas other pixels of let's say value 80 or 90 will not be included. If you will get completely arbitrary and inconsistent results. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes that is what I want. If one heat island in the same vicinity gradually developed from day 65 all the way to day 100 that should be in one group. And if another island develops from day 80 to day 90 in that own spatial proximity it should be a different group. So yes, eventually I would have many different groups (heat islands), some with similar values, some not.

Comment: Added my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402730/88814