# How to group polygons based on spatial proximity and sum of numbers?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

[Similar to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402714/how-to-group-polygons-based-on-spatial-proximity-and-field-value), rather I want to group polygons based on sum of values.
To be more specific, I need to group cities, within a state, and that group must add up to "x" amount of people, in order to create something that looks like [this](https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/7C41/production/_109490813_2_uk_elections_640_-2x_v10-nc.png).

I must also inform that I a complete beginner in python(any coding to be honest).

Comment: Your question is too vague. You'll need to provide a lot more detail - screen shots, samples of data, rules around the grouping (eg proximity, how close to "x") before you will get any useful answers. Keep in mind that questions around 'adding up to "x"' are hard - they depend heavily on the rules. There's not a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can categorize your data using the "Equale Count (Quantile)" mode.
See screenshot below.

[image]